# Aggregating an array of values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of values I want to group by the id of, and get the sum of all the values. Currently I'm trying:

```
db.entries.aggregate(
[
    { $match: {"user": "John" } },
    { "$unwind": '$games'},
    { $group: {
        "_id": "$games.id",
        "score": { "$sum": "$games.score"} }},
])
```

The data looks like:

```
{  
   "user":"john",
   "games":[  
      {  
         "id":123,
         "score":123
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "user":"john",
   "games":[  
      {  
         "id":123,
         "score":123
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "user":"john",
   "games":[  
      {  
         "id":256,
         "score":256
      }
   ]
}
```

In this example, for "John" I would like to get the total of all the unique game scores. I should get (123 + 256) in this example.

However, right now I'm getting the sum of individual games, not all of them as a total.

Comment: Is game always one element array?

Answer (score 0):

I have here:

```
> db.entries.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a9610cca390d7e14a54486"), "user" : "john", "games" : [ { "id" : 123, "score" : 123 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a9610cca390d7e14a54487"), "user" : "john", "games" : [ { "id" : 123, "score" : 123 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a9610cca390d7e14a54488"), "user" : "john", "games" : [ { "id" : 256, "score" : 256 } ] }
> db.entries.aggregate([ {$match: {user: "john"}}, {$unwind: "$games"}, {$group: {_id: "$games.id", score: {$sum: "$games.score"}}} ]);
{ "_id" : 256, "score" : 256 }
{ "_id" : 123, "score" : 246 }
```

What’s the problem?

Comment: I'd really like to get the total score of 379. Note too that the scores from id 123 should only count once.(aka, not be 246)

Comment: It makes no sense. You aggregated by `$game.id`: there’s two IDs (123 and 256). The sum of all games with ID 123 is 246, and the sum of all games (one game in case) with ID 256 is 256. Nothing wrong here. You want just one game per ID and the sum of all elements, isn’t it?

Comment: What I understand you want: `db.entries.aggregate([ {$match: {user: "john"}}, {$group: {_id: "$games.id", score: {$first: "$games.score"}}}, {$unwind: "$score"}, {$group: {_id: 1, score: {$sum: "$score"}}}]);`